# Font Question: inslrmaj

Tags: fonts

I go to

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

to browse for a suitable font.

Most of them don't seem to work with pdftex. For example

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/inslrmaj/

I download the sample .tex, the `inslrmaj` package loads without error. I get two errors that can be resolved by commenting out:

```
\input catalogue
```

and

```
\input fonttable
```

but then the text renders in the default format. How do I get these fonts to work?

Comment: Works for me. Did you add some text after commenting out those lines? Otherwise, the source doesn't actually tell LaTeX to typeset anything in the font.

Answer (score 1):

For example, here's a simplified version of the sample TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inslrmaj, kantlipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\normalfont\imajfamily
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Insular Majuscule]

Answer (score 0):

`\input catalog` inserts the text listed on the webpage and `\input testfont` prints the font table. Both can be done from within a test document. A solution which uses the package `fonttable` instead:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inslrmaj}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\section*{Insular Majuscule}
\subsection*{\textbackslash imajfamily}
\normalfont\imajfamily
Style example For mange Aar siden levede en Keiser, som holdt saa uhyre 
meget af smukke nye Klæder, at han gav alle sine Penge ud for ret at 
blive pyntet. Han brød sig ikke om sine Soldater, brød sig ei om 
Comedie eller om at kjøre i Skoven, uden alene for at vise sine 
nye Klæder.  Han havde en Kjole for hver Time paa Dagen, og ligesom 
man siger om en Konge, han er i Raadet, saa sagde man altid her:  
»Keiseren er i Garderoben!« –

\newpage
\fonttable{imaj17}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]